# Remove object by itself in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, slick2d, single-threaded

I am working with single thread game, in Main class i have ArrayList to contain Bullet objects for attacking zombies.
Each of frame of game i do loop like:

```
ArrayList<Bullet> bulletList;
for (Bullet iBullet : bulletList) {
    iBullet.move();
    iBullet.attack(bulletList);
}
```

In Bullet class, i wrote

```
public void attack(ArrayList<Bullet> bulletList) {
    for (Zombies z : zombieList) {
        if ( hit condition ) {
            bulletList.remove(this); //problem here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I got null error after first loop, seems bullet object had removed successfully from ArrayList and also made some confuses in loop of Main class.

Comment: Use `iterator` if you want to remove element from `List`.

Comment: @vinS It's worse than that. The iterator is still invalidated unless it's the *iterator* `remove` method that's used, so `bulletList.remove(this)` still kills the iterator.

Comment: You are tying to change `bulletList` while iterating over it. That is not possible. Iterate over a copy of the array list : `for (Bullet iBullet : new ArrayList(bulletList)) {`

Comment: I found that
`for (int i=0; i < bulletList.size(); i++) {...}`
work much more smoothly but i am just worry that the loop would omit next items in ArrayList if the previous one had been removed.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), changing your `attack` method to accept it as a parameter:

```
Iterator<Bullet> iterator = bulletList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Bullet iBullet = iterator.next();
    iBullet.move();
    iBullet.attack(bulletList, iterator);
}

public void attack(ArrayList<Bullet> bulletList, Iterator<Bullet> iterator) {
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Or you can change your `attack` method to return a boolean indicating whether the bullet hit or not (instead of removing the bullet), and use the [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method introduced in Java 8:

```
for (Bullet iBullet : bulletList) {
    iBullet.move();
}
bulletList.removeIf(b -> b.attack());
```

Comment: I dont see it's really different from `if (...) bulletList.remove(...);`

Comment: Or do b::attack

Comment: @NguyễnPhanHùngThuận - Updated my answer.